# current dropdown won't close after opening

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this script that opens dropdowns under my navigation items.

Right now, when a navigation item is clicked, the drop down will open. When I click the same item again it will not close.

I am able to close it only if I click on another navigation item to open another dropdown.

How can I get the current navigation item to close when I click it, while keeping the functionality of it closing when other navigation items are clicked?

```
$("li.dropdown-control > a").click( function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
        $('.dropped').removeClass('dropped');
        var nextSibling = $(this).next();
        nextSibling.toggleClass("dropped");  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
    $('.dropped').removeClass('dropped');
    var nextSibling = $(this).next();
    nextSibling.toggleClass("dropped");
```

this will remove ALL the `dropped` classes (including the one you just clicked on, if it's already dropped open) and then add it back to the same element. That's why it never seems to close -- you actually close and open it again immediately.

Try this instead:

```
    var nextSibling = $(this).next();
    nextSibling.toggleClass("dropped");  
    $('.dropped').not(nextSibling).removeClass('dropped');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by removing  `$('.dropped').removeClass('dropped');` line from your code.
toggleClass means add class if not added, or remove class if it has been added.

Now, by removing `$('.dropped').removeClass('dropped');` `toggleClass` will remove `.dropped` class

```
$("li.dropdown-control > a").click( function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
        var nextSibling = $(this).next();
        nextSibling.toggleClass("dropped");  
});
```

Comment: Thanks Boss, I had this before, but encountered an issue with dropdowns staying open after i clicked to open a different drop down.